# table cell height issue iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have custom table view.I have added 4 views in that

1.ImageView 
2.Three labels

[image]

Now I want that image should increase in size for multiple devices.For that i have given it below constraints.Proptional height is **176:339**

[image]

Now in order to increase the height of the image i have increase height of table i used below code.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(!self.customCell)
    {
        self.customCell = [self.tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tableCell"];
    }
    CGFloat height;
    height=self.customCell.img_main.frame.size.height;
    height=height+self.customCell.label_one.frame.size.height;
    height=height+self.customCell.label_two.frame.size.height;
    height=height+self.customCell.label_three.frame.size.height;
    height=height+self.customCell.dev_name.frame.size.height;
    NSLog(@"height is %f",self.customCell.img_main.frame.size.height);

    return height;
}
```

The heigh of image is always 176 which i set in interface builder for 4 inch screen.

Why the height of both images & table view cell is not increasing ?

Comment: Because at that moment when you accessing the frame properties, these views haven't laid out yet, and its' frames not updated yet. 
I suggest you set `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` instead of overriding heightForRowAtIndexPath: method.This will calculate row height of each cell automatically for you.

Comment: what's the proportion between the cell's height and screen height? like `80 : 100?` if you know what the proportion should be, you can return the cell height like `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * 0.8`. And the subview's height will be calculated automatically.

Comment: yes it works.What if i want to increase height according to content not according to the aspect ratio

Comment: @arturdev self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension does not work form me

Answer (score 1):

This is for your second question, if you want to change the image view's height base on the image it display, i suggest to use Height Constraint instead of Proportional Height Constraint, the calculation will be easier. When you get the image, and know the image size, so you calculate and get the size of the image view, and then update the Height Constrains. Done.

drag the constraint to your cell

[image]

update the constraint when image setted

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CustomeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.image = image;
    cell.imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = [self calcuteSizeWithImage:image]; //you need to do the calculation yourself
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: on which basis i calculate the image size ?

Comment: The image size or image view size? If you mean image view, That depends on how you want to adjust the view to its content. For example, If you want the image view to has the aspect ratio of its image and fill the image view with its image, then the image view's height should be imageViewWidth * imageHeight / imageWidth